# Get first uncommented line (i.e not staring with #) in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I am processing a developer commit message in git hook.

let's say the file has the following content

```
\n new lines here
# this is a sample commit
# only for the developers
Ticket-ID: we fix old bugs and introduces new ones
we always do this stuff

so cool, not really :P
# company name
```

My intention is to get only this line `Ticket-ID : we fix old bugs and introduces new ones`

Comment: `cat file | grep -v "#" | head -n 1`

Comment: Or just `cat file | grep "Ticket-ID"`

Comment: Or just `grep 'Ticket-ID' file`.

Comment: @RobertoManfreda Thank you for your answer but if the first line is a new line I'll get just new line character.
also I can't grep ticket id because it can be anything

Comment: `grep -E "^[[:alnum:]]" file |head -n 1` should do....

Comment: @User123 if you can answer below I'll accept your answer.

Comment: So what is the pattern that can be assumed/followed in order to extract/print what you wanted?

Comment: `sed -n '/^[[:alnum:]]/{p;q}' file.txt`

Comment: `grep -Em1 "^[[:alnum:]]" file.txt` GNU `grep`

Comment: `^[[:alnum:]]` will not match commit messages that start with non-alphanumeric characters like emoji, dashes, parenthesis, etc.. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below single line `grep` should work as per your requirement:

```
grep -E "^[[:alnum:]]" file |head -n 1
```

**Explanation:**

```
^[[:alnum:]] :: to capture only the line starting with any alphanumeric character[0-9A-Za-z]

head -n 1 ::  to capture the first occurrence
```

Answer (score 1):

User123's comment is nice and terse: `grep -E "^[[:alnum:]]" file |head -n 1` however is does *not* catch lines of text that start with non-alphanumeric characters that are not a `#` such as commit messages that start with an emoji, dashes, parenthesis, etc..

- yeah this line is an exception
- --> This is also an edge case
- (so is this)

To catch all edge cases you can loop through the file and check each `$line` with a negated `!` regexp operator `=~` for:

1. Not being a newline `! $line =~ (^[^\n ]*$)`
2. Not starting with a pound sign `! $line =~ ^#`
3. Not being a line consisting of all spaces `! $line =~ (^[ ]*$)`

Then just `echo` the `$line` and `break` if those conditions are met:

```sh
# file parse.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -f $1 ]]; then
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    [[ ! $line =~ (^[^\n ]*$) && ! $line =~ ^# && ! $line =~ (^[ ]*$) ]] && echo "$line" && break
  done < "$1"
fi
```

```
# file commit .txt


# this is a sample commit
# only for the developers
Ticket-ID: we fix old bugs and introduces new ones
we always do this stuff

so cool, not really :P
# company name
```

Now you can invoke the `parse.sh` like this

```sh
bash parse.sh commit.txt
```

Or save the results to a variable using a subshell

```sh
result=$(bash parse.sh commit.txt); echo "$result"
```